# Extract Python dictionary from string

Tags: python, regex, django, dictionary, django-views

I have a string with valid python dictionary inside

```
data = "Some string created {'Foo': u'1002803', 'Bar': 'value'} string continue etc."
```

I need to extract that dict. I tried with regex but for some reason `re.search(r"\{(.*?)\}", data)` did not work. Is there any better way extract this dict?

Comment: Where are you getting the string from? Why does it look like that? Could you get it in a more useful format?

Comment: @jonrsharpe why is this important for the question it is as it is, so the question is quite clear.

Comment: Substring out the dictionary, and then use `ast.literal_eval(substr)` to turn it into a dictionary.

Comment: Because you probably have an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/248731), so answering it as posed is wasting your time and ours.

Comment: @Goran Your question is clear in what you want to do, sure. Let's agree on that. But what have you tried so far? Can you show your code to help indicate where your mistakes are being made?

Comment: Also, understandably, this is what you want to do, @jonrsharpe does bring up a good point about there being an XY problem. It could be helpful to entertain the idea that maybe there is an easier way to do what you are trying to do by providing some more details?

Comment: That's a slight improvement, but still gives no context. Could you also expand on *"not work"* with a [mcve]? It matches just fine for me.

Comment: You need your group to include the braces `{}` so you parens `()` need to be outside of the braces in your regex.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

From @AChampion's suggestion.

```
>>> import re
>>> import ast
>>> x = ast.literal_eval(re.search('({.+})', data).group(0))
>>> x
{'Bar': 'value', 'Foo': '1002803'}
```

so the pattern you're looking for is `re.search('({.+})', data)`

You were supposed to extract the curly braces with the string, so `ast.literal_eval` can convert the string to a python dictionary . you also don't need the `r` prefix as `{` or `}` in a capturing group, `()` would be matched literally.

Comment: Note that since the regex is greedy, this still works in the case when there's a nested `dict`, e.g. `"Some string created {'Foo': u'1002803', 'Bar': 'value', 'Baz': {1:2, 3:4}} string continue etc."`. However, it fails if there is more than one separate `dict` in the string. E.g.`"Some string created {'Foo': u'1002803', 'Bar': 'value'} string continue etc. Another dict: {1:2, 3:4}"`. A **parser** is necessary to handle the latter case (or if `{` or `}` could appear anywhere else in the in the string).

Comment: @jpmc26 making it non-greedy (`re.findall(r'{.+?}', data)`) should handle extra occurences of `{ }`. but that would mess up the nested dictionaries as they would be seen as different occurences when they're actually part of a larger group. so yes a parser is actually needed to handle both cases at the same time.

Comment: by the way how did you know that i edited this answer (i was just passing by and fixing some typo's in my old answers :) )

Comment: Editing bumps the question. I happened to see it on the front page. Didn't even notice the date when I commented. lol

Comment: @jpmc26: Can you please elaborate by "using a parser"? I'm stuck with a string like this. I'd really appreciate some help. 
`
 'name: "data dict" id: 2\nv6: false\nstats {\n  hosts {\n    cnt1: 256\n    cnt2: 0\n  }\n  groups {\n    cnt1: 1\n    cnt2: 0\n  }\n  critical {\n    cnt1: 1\n    cnt2: 0\n  }\n  main_hosts {\n    cnt1: 256\n    cnt2: 0\n  }\n}\n group_id: "None"'
`

How do I get the dictionary of a list of dictionaries from this? 
`stats {hosts: {cnt1: 250, cnt2: 0}, groups: {cnt: 1, cnt2: 0}, etc, etc}`

Comment: @PixelatedPixie Please search for a question with similar syntax to yours, and if you cannot find one, post a new question.

Answer (score 5):

Better way of parsing out the dictionary without having to use `eval`:

```
import re
import json

data = "Some string created {'Foo': '1002803', 'Bar': 'value'} string continue"


dict_object = json.loads(re.search('({.+})', data).group(0).replace("'", '"'))
```

**  If dictionary to be parsed contains unicode string values (referencing the question's example string):

```
dict_object = json.loads(re.search('({.+})', data).group(0).replace("u'", '"').replace("'", '"'))
```

Comment: @MatthewBarlowe this does work, tested in Python 3.9.9. 
Furthermore, json.loads is a safer execution then eval, specially so if your string can be filled out by users that could potentially add malicious code.

Comment: @MatthewBarlowe if dictionary to be parsed contains a unicode string value (referencing the original example string) give this a try:
dict_object = json.loads(re.search('({.+})', data).group(0).replace("u'", '"').replace("'", '"'))

Comment: @Boris no it doesn't the `u` in the string from the OP's example causes a parsing error and should be referenced in the answer

Comment: @renzob that should be referenced in the answer since the OP's string contains a `u`

Comment: Agreed `json.loads` is a safer process and a better one but should be able to handle OP's input is all. Comment removed and upvoted

Answer (score 0):

Your solution works!

```
In [1]: import re

In [2]: data = "Some string created {'Foo': u'1002803', 'Bar': 'value'} string continue etc."

In [3]: a = eval(re.search(r"\{(.*?)\}", data).group(0))

In [4]: a
Out[4]: {'Bar': 'value', 'Foo': u'1002803'}
```

Comment: Unnecessary use of `eval`. -1