# parsing string as dict in nested json document

Tags: python, flask, jinja2

In my flask app, I get a json response from an external api call which has nested documents. I noticed one of the fields in the nested document is a string which I'd like to parse as dictionary so I can extract the fields in my html page?

```
import json
from flask import Flask, render_template, jsonify
import requests

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def index():

    url = "http://remote-server/v1/info"
    params = {"offset":0,"limit":10}
    response = requests.post(url, json=params)
    data = response.json()

    print(data)
    ''' 
    >>
    [
        {
            "full_name": "John Doe",
            "email": "jdoe@example.com",
            "content": '{"count":10, "info": {"foo": "bar", "location": "LA"}, "items":["A", "B", "C"]}'
        }
    ]
    '''

    for item in data:
      print(type(item[content]))
    '''
    >>
    <class 'str'>
    '''  
    return render_template('index.html', data=data)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=5000, debug=True)
```

I want to be able to extract `content` like this in my html:

```
# -- index.html
<div>          
  {% for doc in data %}
    <div class="user_info">{{ doc['full_name'] }}</div>
    <div class="user_info">{{ doc['email']  }}</div>
    <div class="user_info">{{ doc['content']['info']['foo'] }}</div>
    <div class="user_info">{{ doc['content']['info']['location'] }}</div>

    {% for item in doc.content.items %}
       <div>{{ item }}</div>
    {% endfor %}   

  {% endfor %}
</div>
```

Comment: Nice question. But please remove the flask dependencie from your minimal working example. Your question do not depend on flask and it would make the MWE more "minimal".

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Extract Python dictionary from string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39807724/extract-python-dictionary-from-string)

Comment: Is it JSON? Are you asking how to parse JSON?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are almost there. It is kinda strange the server is responding with an invalid json. Anyways, double check replacing `'{` by `{` and `}'` by `}` is not going to screw thing up. I just modified your example a little bit like below:

```py
import json
from flask import Flask, render_template_string


app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route('/')
def index():
    template = """
        <div>
          {% for doc in data %}
            <div class="user_info">{{ doc['full_name'] }}</div>
            <div class="user_info">{{ doc['email']  }}</div>
            <div class="user_info">{{ doc['content']['info']['foo'] }}</div>
            <div class="user_info">{{ doc['content']['info']['location'] }}</div>

            {% for item in doc.content.items() %}
               <div>{{ item }}</div>
            {% endfor %}
          {% endfor %}
        </div>
        """

    payload = """
    [
        {
            "full_name": "John Doe",
            "email": "jdoe@example.com",
            "content": '{"count":10, "info": {"foo": "bar", "location": "LA"}, "items":["A", "B", "C"]}'
        }
    ]
    """.replace("'{", "{").replace("}'", "}")

    data = json.loads(payload)
    return render_template_string(template, data=data)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=5000, debug=True)
```

Comment: I ended up using `json.loads`, this one works too. thanks